# Codimension of subspaces of a sphere

Tags: dimension-theory-analysis

Let consider the three following sets :

$S_1 = \{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3\; |\; x^2+y^2+z^2=1 \}$

$S_2 = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2\; |\; \exists z\in \mathbb{R}, \; x^2+y^2+z^2=1 \}$

$S_3 = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}\; |\; \exists z\in \mathbb{R}, \; x^2+z^2=1 \}$

Am I right when saying :
$S_1$ is of codimension 1 in $\mathbb{R}^3$,

$S_2$ is of codimension 1 in $\mathbb{R}^2$,

$S_3$ is of codimension 1 in $\mathbb{R}$

?

Comment: What kind of dimension are we talking about? Also, why the tags linear-algebra and vector-spaces? As far as I can see, your question seems to have nothing to do with these. One more thing, have you noticed that $S_3$ is just the interval $[-1,1]$ and that $S_2$ is the closed disk with radius $1$ and center $(0,0) \in \mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: you are right. I am considering codimension with the rank of the Jacobian matrix of the function f which define the set ($f(x,y,z) = x^2+y^2+z^2$).